# jquery ajax request success portion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I am having this  ajax request but success portion is not working I have been working from past one hour but not able to get is there any thing I am missing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxsearch",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(eval({
        name_startsWith: request.term
    })),

    success: function (data) {
        alert("yoo"); //What ever I write  do not get executed is any thing wrong
    }
});
```

Comment: You should not be using JSONP, `eval`, or headers.

Comment: I am getting data in console . . but success is not working. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to first try to make the jQuery Ajax working with simple code then do modification. You can try the below code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#btnSend").click(function(){
            var args = {
                    url : "http://localhost:8080/JqueryAjaxPrj/CustomerServlet",
                    type : "POST",
                    success : handleResponse,
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {my-status: "test", my-name: "xyz"}
            };
            $.ajax(args);
        });
    });

    function handleResponse(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnSend">Send Request</button>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks friend by writing success like
---- "success : handleResponse," it worked. .So have accepted your answer ,I have low point so can't vote up

Comment: Nice... have you changed dataType from 'jsonp' to 'json' ?

Answer (score 1):

1. `url: "ajaxsearch"` is most likely something like `url: "ajaxsearch.php"` / `url: "ajaxsearch.ashx"`
2. Are you sure that the dataType is `jsonp` and not `json`?
3. Don't `eval()` - it's evil
4. Inspect the error on why you aren't ending up in the success handler:

   `error: function(jqXhr, status, error) { /* handle error here */ }`
5. Since it's a search, you should use `type: 'GET'` instead of POST. POST is usually used when saving data to the server (like when submitting a form, for example. This is just a general guideline. `GET` is default, so you could just remove the property.

Comment: Actually I am getting data back when I see in console. . 
but still I am unable to reach to success part. .
I was implementing http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp with spring at server side . . server side worked fine. . but client side I am unable to debug.